# Android Wear Notification action error message

Tags: android

On Android Wear, starting with API level 23, I keep getting the message

> "Problem completing your action"

when performing a notification action which creates a broadcast. But the action is performed correctly and app operation continues normal. There's also no error message in the logs.

There's no such error message in lower API levels. The message only appears for notifications launched from a wear application. Notifications which were created on a phone and shown on the wearable device are not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by **setting** the pacakge name on the *Intent*, which was used to create the *PendingIntent* for the *Action*.

So by **leaving out** the following line

```
intent.setPackage("my.package.name");
```

the problem was resolved.

Comment: What could be the reason that setPackage(..) is causing the "Problem completing your action" issue?